# How to type a reusable controller for react-hook-form?

Tags: react-hook-form

I have an Ionic React app and I'm using react-hook-form v7.

I want to create a reusable textarea component that I can use across forms.

Here is my component:

```
type ControllerTextareaProps<T extends FieldValues> = {
  control: Control<T>;
  clearErrors: UseFormClearErrors<T>;
  name: TextareaNameAttribute;
  label: string;
  labelPlacement?: 'stacked' | 'floating';
};

const ControllerTextarea: React.FC<ControllerTextareaProps<FieldValues>> = ({
  control,
  clearErrors,
  label,
  name,
  labelPlacement,
}: ControllerTextareaProps<FieldValues>) => (
  <Controller
    control={control}
    name={name}
    rules={{ required: true }}
    render={({
      field: { onChange, onBlur, value },
      fieldState: { invalid, isTouched },
    }) => (
      <IonTextarea
        className={setFormControllerImportClass(invalid, isTouched)}
        label={label}
        labelPlacement={labelPlacement}
        name={name}
        value={value}
        onIonBlur={onBlur}
        onIonChange={(
          event: IonTextareaCustomEvent<TextareaChangeEventDetail>,
        ) => {
          clearErrorsIfInvalid(invalid, name, clearErrors);
          if (event?.detail.value) {
            onChange(event?.detail.value);
          }
        }}
        rows={5}
        fill="solid"
        autoGrow
        clearOnEdit={false}
      />
    )}
  />
);

ControllerTextarea.defaultProps = {
  labelPlacement: 'floating',
};

export default ControllerTextarea;
```

The problem is that when I pass a `control` prop, it has the the type of the field values of the form (`Control<MyFormFieldValues>`).  So I tried to use a generic instead.

However, when I add the component to a form, I get an error:

```
Type 'Control<{ mail: string; message: string; }, any>' is not assignable to type 'Control<FieldValues>'.
  Types of property '_reset' are incompatible.
    Type 'UseFormReset<{ mail: string; message: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'UseFormReset<FieldValues>'.
      Types of parameters 'values' and 'values' are incompatible.
        Type 'FieldValues | { [x: string]: any; } | ResetAction<FieldValues> | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ mail: string; message: string; } | { mail?: string | undefined; message?: string | undefined; } | ResetAction<{ mail: string; message: string; }> | undefined'.
          Type 'ResetAction<FieldValues>' is not assignable to type '{ mail: string; message: string; } | { mail?: string | undefined; message?: string | undefined; } | ResetAction<{ mail: string; message: string; }> | undefined'.
            Type 'ResetAction<FieldValues>' is not assignable to type 'ResetAction<{ mail: string; message: string; }>'.
              Type 'FieldValues' is not assignable to type '{ mail: string; message: string; }'.
```

Here's the form:

```
  const { clearErrors, handleSubmit, control, reset } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      mail: userObject ? userObject.emailAddress : '',
      message: '',
    },
  });

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <IonItem>
        <ControllerTextarea
          control={control}
          clearErrors={clearErrors}
          name={TextareaNameAttribute.Message}
          label={messageLabel}
        />
      </IonItem>
    </form>
  );
```

I don't understand generics very well so I might be missing something obvious.  What is going wrong here?  How can I ensure that the field values (`mail` and `message` get typed as `<FieldValues>`)?